# How to load a tag script with js file only once

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

As well as "require" in Ruby. Assuming that I call by accident, more than once a particular script in a single processing. How to make it to be loaded only once in html?

```
# app/assets/javascripts/file3.js
//= require file1
//= require file2

# app/assets/javascripts/file2.js
//= require file1

# app/assets/javascripts/file1.js
(function ($) {
    console.log('time');
}());

# app/views/layouts/something.haml
- content_for :layout_head do
  = javascript_include_tag 'file3'

- content_for :layout_body do
  %main
    %section
      #container
        = yield

= render file: 'layouts/application'
```

should generate:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/assets/file1.self.js?body=1"></script>
        <script src="/assets/file2.self.js?body=1"></script>
        <script src="/assets/file3.self.js?body=1"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

should not generate:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/assets/file1.self.js?body=1"></script>
        <script src="/assets/file1.self.js?body=1"></script>
        <script src="/assets/file2.self.js?body=1"></script>
        <script src="/assets/file3.self.js?body=1"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```